Android BLE Advertising: Can not remove onAdvertisingSetStopped() Callback
I'm having trouble with BLE advertising on Android.
When I turn off Bluetooth while advertising, the advertisement correctly stops and the onAdvertisingSetStopped callback is triggered.
However, when I turn Bluetooth back on, the advertisement doesn't restart automatically.
Calling startAdvertising manually works, but then turning Bluetooth off again results in onAdvertisingSetStopped being called twice, because I did'n call stopAdvertising method.
Since the BluetoothAdapter is unavailable when Bluetooth is off, I cannot call stopAdvertisingSet in my stopAdvertising method.
I also tried using enableAdvertising(true, 0, 0) on the existing currentAdvertisingSet after toggling Bluetooth, but that didn't resolve the issue.
Here are relevant code snippets:
private var currentAdvertisingSet: AdvertisingSet? = null
    private lateinit var parameters: AdvertisingSetParameters

    // called from broadcastreceiver
    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
    private fun restartAdvertising() {
        currentAdvertisingSet?.let {
            it.enableAdvertising(true,0,0)
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopAdvertising()
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        startAdvertising()
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    } 

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
    private fun startAdvertising(){
      
        val advertiser = (this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager)
            .adapter
            .bluetoothLeAdvertiser

        parameters = AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
            .setLegacyMode(false)
            .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MEDIUM)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .setPrimaryPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_1M)
            .setSecondaryPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_CODED)
            .build()

        val sendingData = AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)            .addServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(this.resources.getString(R.string.service_uuid))))
            .addServiceData(          ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(this.resources.getString(R.string.service_uuid))),
                message.toByteArray()
            )
            .build()

        advertiser.startAdvertisingSet(
            parameters,
            sendingData,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            advertiseCallback
        )
    }

    private val advertiseCallback = object : AdvertisingSetCallback() {
        override fun onAdvertisingSetStarted(
            advertisingSet: AdvertisingSet?,
            txPower: Int,
            status: Int
        ) {
            super.onAdvertisingSetStarted(advertisingSet, txPower, status)
            when (status) {
                ADVERTISE_SUCCESS -> {
                    currentAdvertisingSet = advertisingSet
                }

                else -> {
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onAdvertisingEnabled(
            advertisingSet: AdvertisingSet?,
            enable: Boolean,
            status: Int
        ) {
            super.onAdvertisingEnabled(advertisingSet, enable, status)
            Log.i(
                LOG_TAG,
                "onAdvertisingEnabled(): enable:$enable , status: $status"
            )
        }

        override fun onAdvertisingSetStopped(advertisingSet: AdvertisingSet?) {
            super.onAdvertisingSetStopped(advertisingSet)
            Log.w(
                LOG_TAG,
                "onAdvertisingSetStopped()"
            )
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE)
    private fun stopAdvertising() {
        try {
            val advertiser = (this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager)
                .adapter
                .bluetoothLeAdvertiser
            advertiser.stopAdvertisingSet(advertiseCallback)
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stopAdvertising(): ${e.message}")
        }
    }

Is there a recommended way to properly remove/invalidate the existing callback and ensure a clean restart of the advertisement after Bluetooth is toggled?
I'm looking for a reliable solution to avoid duplicate onAdvertisingSetStopped calls.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
